# How to solve error in latex beamer compilation

Tags: beamer, errors, compiling

When I was making my presentation using LaTeX and Beamer,
suddenly I found an error in compiling:

> Text line contains an invalid character.

Line number is given and it shows the error is in the preamble.
If we delete that line then also the same error occurs and there is no change in the line number. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: most likely it is an ascii null (byte 0) which you can not see.  If you can not delete the line with your editor, start with a new file and copy the text (from the next line to the end) into the new file and then just re-type the initial part then just use the new file and discard the invalid one..

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you sure that it is in the preamble? Line numbers refers to the currently open file not to the main file. You could add something like this `\catcode\`\^^00=13 \def^^00{I'm here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!}` and then look for the "i'm here" text.